# Debugger LLDB for C not working properly in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, lldb

Well i have a project that i have to re-create the behavior of **printf** with flags, i'm using **VSCode** to debug using only **LLDB**, i'm using [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) and also [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) extensions to debug, my problem is the debugger can't enter and debug the function for example `putd`

```
if (*onchar == 'd')
    putd(onchar, mydata, list);
```

I have a breakpoint in the line where the function is and inside the function as well, it just skip it and give me the result, the function works fine all good, but only the debugger can't enter the function.

And this is my config in `launch.json`

```
{
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

PS: `putd.c` is a separate file that i call in my function, and i include it in the `mylib.h` and in the `Makefile` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out , i should've compile all the `.c` files, i didn't compile all of them, while using `gcc -g *.c`  i just compiled the `main.c` only.